# Create div with triangle border in css

Tags: css

I am trying to create a div with arrow on left and right. No background, only border.  Something like this:

[image]

I am able to create similar div with filled background color using ::before  and ::after tags. However, only borders is something i am not able to achieve. Can it be done with css only?

https://jsfiddle.net/1g16x8p7/1/

html:

```
<div class="wizard">
  <a class="item">
  </a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left: 25px;

    /*default styles*/
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
  }  


 .item:before,
.item:after {
      content: "";
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
      border-width: 15px 0 15px  10px;
      border-style: solid;

      position: absolute;
      left: 100%;
      top: 0;
    }


.item:before {
          border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
        left: 0;  
      }


.item:after {
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;  
      }
```

Comment: Can you show what you created? With filled background?

Comment: The web (HTML) is made of boxes, so no. The best you can do is a `transform: skew(45deg);` combining 2 divs together. You also got to think of how content will fill that irregular shape. SVG is what you want if you are going to get crazy with shapes.

Comment: @blackandorangecat Added JSFiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `::before` and `::after` with borders on two adjacent sides (e.g. top and right) and then `transform: rotate` and `position: absolute` them to create the left and right parts, e.g.

`<div class="arrow"></div>`

```
.arrow {
  height: 75px;
  width: 200px;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.arrow::before, .arrow::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);

}

.arrow::before {
  top: 8px;
  left: -30px;
}

.arrow::after {
  top: 8px;
  right: -30px;
}
```

Here's [an example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LOVeeJ).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! :)